# Having multiple (seperate) Attachment Tables related to one feature class

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, attachments

Is it possible to have multiple attachment tables related to one feature class?

The purpose is to only show specific attachments at certain times. We are trying to only show pertinent attached files/docs/PDFs to multiple viewers.  So Sales People would only be able to see attachments related to sales, and Drafting would only see attachments related to their department.

Some of our features can have over ten attachments, but when we publish a map they don't want to see all of the related attachments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can enable attachments more than once per feature class. The easiest way would be to have different feature classes for which attachments you want visible through the feature service.